# Dynamically update batch size of input for spark kafka consumer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use `createDirectStream` in my spark streaming application. I set the batch interval to 7 seconds and most of the time the batch job can finish within about 5 seconds. However, in very rare cases, the batch job need cost 60 seconds and this will delay some batch of jobs.
To cut down the total delay time, I hope I can process more streaming data which spread over the delayed jobs at one time. This will help the streaming return to normal as soon as possible.

So, I want to know there is some method to dynamically update/merge batch size of input for spark and kafka when delay appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled" option to true.

If the batch delay occurs when the backpressure option is true, it initially starts with a small batch size and then dynamically changes to a large batch size.

[See the spark configuration document.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

You can see the description below.

> Enables or disables Spark Streaming's internal backpressure mechanism
>   (since 1.5). This enables the Spark Streaming to control the receiving
>   rate based on the current batch scheduling delays and processing times
>   so that the system receives only as fast as the system can process.
>   Internally, this dynamically sets the maximum receiving rate of
>   receivers. This rate is upper bounded by the values
>   spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate and
>   spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition if they are set (see below).